# Working out percentage of how many stay in a company

Tags: excel

I have a table that collects employee information and I want to work out the sustained rate of a department so calculating how many stay after the 6 month period within a given year. I can manually do it by taking the `Start Date` month and then going 7 months forward (to ensure I capture the whole previous month) to then checking to see how many are `Sustained` and how many `Left` the business (Sustained / Monthly Start Date Total).

Note my sustained data ignores the start Day as its based on the month and not the day so if some are counted before sustaining thats fine.

My Table:

```
******************************************************************
Name    *    Start Date    *   Department    *  Sustained/Left   *
******************************************************************
Bob     *    21/01/2016    *   Admin         *  Left             *
Jenny   *    08/01/2016    *   Sales         *  Sustained        *
Ralph   *    20/02/2016    *   Admin         *  Sustained        *
Tim     *    18/01/2016    *   IT            *  Sustained        *
Bob     *    06/03/2016    *   Admin         *  Left             *
******************************************************************
```

The report:

```
*********************
Department: * Admin *
*********************

*****************
Jan * Feb * Mar *
*****************
0% * 100&* 0%  *
*****************
```

I will just type the department but for the life of me I cant figure it out. I attempted `SUMPRODUCT` & `COUNTIFS` but i just couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

- you specify the department in cell G3
- your sheet is set up like mine:

[image]

Enter the following into F7:

```
=SUM(($C$4:$C$8=$G$3)*($D$4:$D$8=$E7)*(MONTH($B$4:$B$8)=MONTH(DATEVALUE(F$6&" 1"))))
```

And press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to enter the array formula.

- Then copy cell F7 to G7:Q7
- Then copy cell F7 to F8:Q8

I'm guessing you can take it from there.